# How to add Bearer token to headers of generated api endpoint from openapi-generator-cli

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swagger, bearer-token, openapi-generator

I am testing the [openapi-generator-cli](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-cli) to generate services for a **React** client app from a **swagger.json** file.

Now some routes are protected and require a **Bearer token** in the headers. The token is returned after login.

Is there a possibility to add them as a config or header parameter when calling the generated methods of protected routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my component I am implementing the Api with a service which takes the configuration as a parameter.

myToken is a local variable where I stored the token previously.

```
import * as Api from '../../api/src';
const configParameters: Api.ConfigurationParameters = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myToken,
  },
};
const configuration = new Api.Configuration(configParameters);
const myService = new Api.MyApi(configuration);
```

Comment: should explain your answer instead of just dumping code

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ what explanation do you need?

Comment: I agree with @alex351 I don't see why downvotes as this is the right answer and it helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: This answer is not relevant now, please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @alex351 is not relevant by this moment, since openapi-generator-cli has changed the API.

Now, the correct way to pass token would be smth like this:

```
// this should get a new access token or smth
async function resolveToken() {
    return Promise.resolve('token');
};

const configuration = createConfiguration({
    authMethods: {
      bearerAuth: {
        tokenProvider: {
          getToken: () => await resolveToken(),
        },
      },
    },
  });

const apiInstance = new Api(configuration);
```